# How to send an Notification Email in UrbanCode deploy?

Tags: notifications, continuous-integration

I am working on IBM UrbanCode Deploy. I want send an email notification from urbancode deploy regarding the deployment status. I am unable to configure the email notification for that. How do i can send an email to a developer or a person about the deployment status through urbancode deploy. Can any one help me about this in a detailed manner. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: UrbanCode tool dont have an option to write code. Its tool we have to configure in the tool itself.

Comment: So your question is not about programming, but using a program? If yes, you'll get help at http://superuser.com and this question is likely to be closed as off-topic (see http://stackoverflow.com/help for details).

Comment: I wanted to know email notification configuration in UCD. Their is no need to write any program for that. I configured the notifications as per the manual available in IBM knowledge center still it wont work. So, If you people having knowledge on UrbanCode Deploy.Please, Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar thread on the Urbancode forums:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/14809/how-to-set-email-notification-in-udeploy.html